# Creating gifs with lua

Tags: lua, gif

I am trying to create a .gif image from a number of .png or .jpg images, from within lua code. I've got basic file input and output functions at my disposal. Would this be possible without third party programs, and if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically yes it's possible, but not with any default set of libs.  You'd basically have to "roll your own" to get it.  If the issue is that you cannot use third party libraries, then you're in a bit of a pickle.  If you can use third-party libs, check out `lua-gd` here:  https://ittner.github.io/lua-gd/manual.html

Comment: Using a third party library might be possible, but I would have no idea how to. Since I use lua in a a game's environment

Comment: Oh, if you're using the canned lua interface in something like WoW, you likely won't be able to access external libraries and wrappers. :(

Comment: Yeah, in my case it's the game MTA (Multi Theft Auto)